# Does disabling graphics game objects prevent them from being affected by scripts?

Tags: unity-game-engine, parallax

I'm using frames (bounding boxes) to disable all game objects within an area when the player is not in that area. I want to know if parallax scripts will affect a disabled frame of objects. I don't want the parallax of background and foreground layers to be off when the player enters a new frame.

Slightly off-topic, but still relevant enough: I'm building the frames to be seemless transitions; is there a way to prevent parallax overlap at the transition point?

Comment: `I'm using frames to disable all game objects within an area` - what frames?
Your question is impossible to understand without wild guesses. **Be very specific.**

Comment: Guess this is due to a difference in vocabulary use (iirc, I'm not the only one who has used the term in the context of "framing" objects), not the actual question itself. "Frames" in my question is referring to bounding boxes for different areas. Though, I figured it would have been more or less self-explanatory after saying I was disabling all game objects in a specific area. But yeah, frames = bounding box. Maybe that word confuses some people who are thinking about frames as a computing term.

Comment: In Cg context 'frame' means 'frame buffer'. Bounding box is AABB. Flowery language is admirable but it renders understanding impossible when asking a technical question.

Comment: But he's not asking in a specific computer graphics context, he's asking in a game development context. Its marked as Unity3d, not CG. In that sense, a frame can be many things. Although an unusual use, OP is not wrong. No need to get so condecending!

Comment: @Photon can you elaborate what you mean with `parallax scripts`? Is that a script that you made, i dont think its something built into Unity. Can you elaborate on why you disable scripts outside a bounding box?

Comment: The parallax scripts are just referring to the code that offsets the background and foreground layers based on the player camera. It's being done manually. The method doesn't matter so much as whether disabled game objects are affected by it while disabled. If disabled game objects are still affected by scripts attached to them, then that would result in areas far away from the player having incorrect parallax when the player enters those areas (since the parallax is based on player camera). At the moment, I'm just using generic 2D parallax logic. Nothing really unique.

Comment: @TJHeuvel His question is probably very simple but no one answered it yet precisely because it's so vague. I'm not being condescending just trying to help. Ps: game engines are Cg tho, calling a culling frustum a "camera man eyes" won't help anyone necessarily.

Comment: I don't think it's vague, but it seems the vocabulary (the use of "frame" referring more like a picture frame, that would enclose contents in a boxed area) used might be taken literally by many people who are of higher expertise and have backgrounds that prompt them to read it as such. In the most basic sense, I want to know if game objects are affected by scripts while they are disabled. I included graphics assets because that was specifically what I was caring about being affected.

Comment: > Ps: game engines are Cg tho
Game engines are a lot more than CG. Especially artists use the term frame for a lot more, and in this case he's framing a camera.

Comment: @Photon Thank you! That's was more specific :) My job is done here.

Comment: @TJHeuvel Ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts on disabled gameobjects do not recieve Update calls, as you've noticed. There are a few things you can do:

- Not disable the entire gameobject when its outside the camera frame, instead only disable the renderer attached. This way your parralax script is still updated. Though its questionable if there are performance benefits to this, Unity does Frustrum culling by default.
- Dont have individual parallax scripts, instead have one ParallaxManager in which you register all objects. This manager is never disabled, as an added benefit there is less overhead calling update.
- Instead of update start some coroutine on another object, that isnt disabled. For example, in Parallax you can start a coroutine from the Camera gameobject. That way it keeps going, eventhough the parallax is disabled.
- Try to calculate the right position in the OnEnable. That way you can still disable objects, and they appear at the right position when they are enabled again.